# package com.example.model does not exist

Tags: java, servlets

I have two java files. My first java file is in path which i hava compiled sucessfully:

```
C:\MyProject\BeerV1\source\com\example\model\BeerExpert.java
```

---

```
package com.example.model;
import java.util.*;
public  class BeerExpert
{
  public List getBrands(String color)



package  com.example.web;
import com.example.model.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class BeerSelect extends HttpServlet
{
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws IOException, ServletException
{
    String c = request.getParameter("color");
    BeerExpert be = new BeerExpert();
    List  result = be.getBrands(c);
 response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out =response.getWriter();

out.println("Beer Selection Advice<br>");
//String c = request.getParameter("color");
//out.println("<br>Got beer color "+c);
        Iterator it = result.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
                out.print("<br> try: " +it.next()); 
}       
}
}
```

following is the path i am using for compiling but i am getting following error

```
C:\>javac -cp "C:\MyProject\BeerV1\source\com\example\model\*;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\servlet-api.jar" 
C:\MyProject\BeerV1\source\com\example\web\BeerSelect.java

C:\MyProject\BeerV1\source\com\example\web\BeerSelect.java:2: 
error: package com.example.model does not exist
import com.example.model.*;
^
```

Comment: is the class that you are trying to import on the classpath of the file you are trying to compile?

Comment: no i am trying to compile BeerSelect.java file an i have imported BeerExpert.java file in beerSelect.java file  but i am getting the above error

Comment: `com\example\model` is a package. You should put in the classpath the base folder : use `javac -cp "C:\MyProject\BeerV1\source;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\servlet-api.jar" C:\MyProject\BeerV1\source\com\example\web\BeerSelect.java`

Answer (score -1):

You should have a structure for your project like so:

[$ProjectRoot] > **src** > **main** > **java** > com > example > model

Comment: it's not a maven project